# Can't get Play evolutions to work

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

I have a Play 2.3.7 project and somehow evolutions do not work for me. 
I use Scala 2.11 with sbt 0.13.5. Also Scala.js is used so folder structure is a bit unusual for the Play project. 
I have config file that says `applyEvolutions.default=true` and I specified my default db as Postgres. 
Any idea about what's wrong? I have my models folder in `jvm/app/models`, may be that's the reason? 
Also, can someone please explain how evolutions work (at least at a high level)? Does it know model classes' fields and track which ones are already represented in my database?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: @M-N what I think - although I don't have any source to back this up - evolution scripts are not auto-generated. e.g. if you want to add a field, you manually add a new file with up and down instructions and then Play! applies it when starting

Comment: @M-N also, if I remember correctly, Play applied evolutions I had - I just expected to see more tables (it was not a project I started, so I wasn't sure how data was stored)

Comment: yeah, thanks, I was working on someone else code too, and the problem here was jdbc dependency, that was not added to build.sbt

Answer (score 0):

Play documentation is pretty straight forward for reference about play evolution: [Evolution](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions)

> Play tracks your database evolutions using several evolutions script. These scripts are written in plain old SQL and should be located in the conf/evolutions/{database name} directory of your application. If the evolutions apply to your default database, this path is conf/evolutions/default.

where the Ups part describes the required transformations, and the Downs part that describes how to revert them.